# how to retrieve one data in EAV laravel if there is the same data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, jquery-select2, entity-attribute-value

I have a database with the EAV Entity-attribute-value model, if there is the same data how do I only display the same data once?
for example i have table user

```
id  user_id     name   user_value_name   user_value
1     2         vandy  useraddress       new york
3     2         vandy  userscore_tesA    90
4     2         vandy  userscore_tesB    30
5     3         ahmad  useraddress       japan
6     3         ahmad  userscore_tesA    80
7     3         ahmad  userscore_tesB    70
```

How do I get my name to be displayed only once?
here I will use jquery select2 to display the data

```
$('#name').select2({
      placeholder: "Choose User...",
      ajax: {
        url: "{{ route('getUserFullname') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function(data) {
          return {
            results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                    return {
                    "id": obj.user_id,
                    "text": obj.name,
                    };
            })
          };
        },
      }
    });
```

in my controller, I only take data from the database and json's return response

```
$user = DB::table(users)->get();
return response()->json($user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct` method in Laravel's **QueryBuilder** to solve this.

```
$user = DB::table(users)->distinct('name')->get();
return response()->json($user);
```

In essence, it is a pretty way in Laravel that calls `SELECT DISTINCT` in **SQL**...